# Phonegap Android tap and hold

Tags: android, cordova, touch-event, touchstart

i m using a version of the code found ove [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710111/determining-long-tap-long-press-tap-hold-on-android-with-jquery)

```
var startTime, endTime;
                document.getElementById(queryid).addEventListener('touchstart',function() {
                    startTime = new Date().getTime(); 
                },false);

                document.getElementById(queryid).addEventListener('touchend',function(event) {
endTime = new Date().getTime();
if((endTime-startTime) > 1000)
    alert('tap hold event'); 
                },false);
```

it does the "trick" of tap and hold before someaction, but my problem is that action is triggered only if i stop touching the screen, while i want action to be triggered after tapping for at least i.e. 1sec no matter if i stop touching the screen or not..

this one seems closer to what i want, but it doesn't seem complete..(to my understanding..
gbStillTouching is always false? i don't see anywhere getting toggled..
gnstarttime ==nid? isn't nid=gnstarttime?

```
var gnStartTime = 0;
var gbMove = false;
var gbStillTouching = false;

  function checkTapHold(nID) {
if ((!gbMove) && (gbStillTouching) && (gnStartTime == nID)) {
  gnStartTime = 0;
 gbMove = false; 
 alert('tap hold event');    
 }
 }

window.addEventListener('touchstart',function(event) {
  gnStartTime = Number(new Date());
  setTimeout('checkTapHold(' + gnStartTime + ');clearTimeout();',2000);
},false);

window.addEventListener('touchmove',function(event) {
  gbMove = true;
},false);

window.addEventListener('touchend',function(event) {
 gbStillTouching = false;
  },false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution to the problem, after some useful help from a friend..

```
                var gnStartTime = 0;
                var gbStillTouching = false;
                function checkTapHold(nID) {
                    if ((gbStillTouching) && (gnStartTime == nID)) {
                        gnStartTime = 0;
                        lastClickedId = queryid; 
                        }
                    }
                document.getElementById(queryid).addEventListener('touchstart',function(event) {
                    gnStartTime = Number(new Date());
                    gbStillTouching = true;
                    setTimeout(function() {checkTapHold(gnStartTime);clearTimeout();},1000);
                    },false);
                document.getElementById(queryid).addEventListener('touchend',function(event) {
                    gbStillTouching = false;
                    },false);
```

this works perfectly..after having tapped for at least 1 sec, i can have the required action.. :)